# Laravel listener only sends when I dd a variable in the class being called

Tags: php, laravel

I have a custom class in Laravel that tracks the analytics of my app through Segment (using this package for php: https://github.com/AltThree/Segment).

Here is a snippet of my class and a function I am calling through my listener to track a login:

```
class Tracking {

  private function segmentTrack(User $user, string $event, array $properties = null) {
    $segment = Segment::track([
      "userId" => $user->id,
      "event" => $event,
      "properties" => $properties
    ]);

    dd($segment);
  }

  /**
    * Handle Login tracking
    *
    * @param User $user
    * @return void
    */
  public function login (User $user) {
    $this->segmentTrack($user, "Login");
  }
}
```

Notice the dd in the segmentTrack function. When I run the Laravel queue and I then trigger the `Tracking->login()` event through my app, the listener goes off fine and with the dd function, it will send that data to Segment and I can see it in their live debugger, all is well.

However, when I remove that dd, and the listener goes off and shows as successful - the data is never seen in Segment.

Can someone tell me what i'm missing? This is my first time using the Laravel queue system so a little confused why it might not be working.

Comment: does your ./project/storage/logs/laravel.log show any error?

Comment: nope @SérgioReis - i'm running tail on the logs so would see an error if it popped up as soon as the event triggered.

Comment: if you add `Log::info("just seeing if i get here")` does it write to the log?

Comment: Yep it logs: `[2018-03-16 17:18:22] dev.INFO: just seeing if i get here` - thanks for your quick responses @SérgioReis

Comment: Afraid i can't help much more, i have no knowledge of segment.

Comment: out of curiosity what does it log if you `Log::info($segment)`?

Comment: Thanks anyways! Guess i'll just use an `exit()` function or something. If I Log `$segment` it just gives me a boolean. Just tested using `exit()` and it's working too.

Comment: @SérgioReis lol -> https://github.com/AltThree/Segment/issues/6

Comment: ahah, the joys of developing

Answer (score 1):

For queued jobs, use:

```
Segment::track($payload);

Segment::flush();
```